# Perl XML::Twig doesn't escape double quotes

Tags: perl, xml-twig

I wrote a small script, which parses a XML-file, deletes some redundant elements and writes the rest back to a new XML-file using `$xml->print_to_file();`.

Everything works fine, except that double quotes inside the tag's text, which have been escaped with `&quot;` are normal double quotes now. I didn't find a config similar to `escape_gt` to prevent this behaviour. Is there such a config or an other way to keep double quotes escaped?

My twig config looks like this:

```
my $xml = XML::Twig->new(
    twig_handlers => {
        label => \&purge_file
    },
    pretty_print => 'indented',
    output_encoding => 'utf-8',
    escape_gt => 1
);
```

Comment: Why does it matter? Except inside attribute values that are delimited with double quotes `"` and `&quot;` mean exactly the same thing (except one takes 500% more bytes to do so).

Comment: neither the double quotes nor the greater than need to be escaped. You only need to escaped double quotes in attribute values _if_ the attribute value is double quoted, and the greater than if it comes after a ]]: ']]>' is the end of CDATA section delimiter and for some reason the spec forbids it in all other cases.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's no reason to escape quotes in XML text. Double-quotes only need to be escaped in attribute values quoted with double-quotes, and I'm sure you'll find that XML::Twig escapes those.

---

...but it is possible by mucking with XML::Twig's guts:

```
XML::Twig::Elt::set_replaced_ents(qq{&<>"});  # "&" needs to be first.
```

I recommend against this.

Comment: Oh... Ok, I thought it would matter in some cases... Thanks anyway.

Comment: Updated answer to include a solution anyway.